# StyledText visible lines count

Tags: java, swt

I would like to know how many lines are actually displayed by StyledText. Is it that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// The index of the last (possibly only partially) visible line of the widget
int bottomIndex = JFaceTextUtil.getPartialBottomIndex((StyledText)widget);
// The index of the first (possibly only partially) visible line of the widget
int topIndex = JFaceTextUtil.getPartialTopIndex((StyledText)widget);


int visibleLines = bottomIndex - topIndex;
```

Comment: it worked! I found also another way to do it, but yours better. getBounds().height / (getLinePixel(2) - getLinePixel(1)